# Consume Rest web service with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

This is my json data from my web service

```
[{"cameraid":"ggh","timestamp":"2016/05/10 01:31","filename":"ffffpg"},
{"cameraid":"mason","timestamp":"2016/05/10 05:31","filename":"aaa.png"}
```

My html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="camListApp">
<head>
    <title>hi AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp');
    camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    function Hello($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost/camera/list').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.record= data;
            });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <table border = 1>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>camid</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Filename</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="record in record">
        <td>{{record.cameraid}}</td>
        <td>{{record.timestamp}}</td>
        <td>{{record.filename}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: no data on table]

When I run my browser, no data is show in the table. What have I miss out or done wrong? Anybody can help? As i want to display all the data in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are below issues in your code, which once fixed will make yor code working:

1. Missing `[]` from module definition. Change it as below:

   ```
   var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []);
   ```
2. The controller definition is incorrect as you have 2 callback functions (One within other). You only need one:

   ```
   camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
     $http.get('http://localhost/camera/list').
       success(function(data) {
           $scope.record= data;
       });
   }]);
   ```

Also the preferred way of handlin promises is using `.then` instead of `.success`

3. When you use the `$http` service it wraps up your data in an object and actual data is an attribute exposed on the returned response in callback. Access the `data` attribute in response as below:

   ```
   $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/addi90/repos').then(function(response) {
     $scope.records= response.data;
   });
   ```

I have created a working bin with sample data from my github repos: https://jsbin.com/qejapayuhi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Hi, it still does not show me any data. But do you think i set my ng-repeat wrongly?

Comment: Change your scope variable to `$scope.records` and in `ng-repeat="record in records"`. Dont refer with the same name for the iteration variable as your collection

Comment: Still no data after changing the ng-repeat

Comment: I have update the response and added a working jsbin for your issue

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML you need to name the app:

```
<html ng-app="camListApp">
```

And then in your script you need to define the controller and the app, and bring in the services. Add, around the function:

```
var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp');
camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
   // existing code
}
```

Angular is pretty fussy about these things. Since I can't easily reproduce your app, I'll be interested to find out if this worked for you.

Comment: Hi, i edited my code. It does not display any data in my table.